# granular kusto query visualised

Tags: graph, kql, appinsights

I am sending customMetric to azure app-insights about payment success - 0 if payment failed and 1 if payment was successful.

So for I have this query:

```
customMetrics
| where name startswith "PaymentSuccess"
| summarize event_count=count() by format_datetime(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
| order by timestamp desc
| render columnchart
```

and there are two problems with this query - where there is "empty date" it wont be shown in a graph and also I would like to make graph show how many times there were 0s and 1s, now its just a count of "occurrences"

[image]

Comment: "how many times there were 0s and 1s" - where?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz per each day. Now each each line on a picture represents what happened in a day - but cumulatively - how many such metrics were logged. I would like to have two series of data - one for success and one for failure

Comment: Do you have a column with 0 / 1 / success / failure / true / false values?

Comment: yes, the column is called `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[make-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator) operator

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let customMetrics = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend name = "PaymentSuccess", timestamp = ago(rand() * 60d), value = iff(rand() < 0.3, 0, 1));
// Solution Starts here.
customMetrics
| where name startswith "PaymentSuccess"
| where timestamp !between (ago(20d) .. ago(10d))
| make-series  event_count = count() on timestamp step 1d by tostring(value)
| render timechart
```

[image: ADX]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WQS07DQBBE9z5FkZWNjD8gsQGOAELyAVDHbtsjPDPRTDshKIen7QARYjWfriq9rrJEQ3Y3MToSwsCOA4nxrsCLF+woCHwPGRnRT/M6SSYWtHMUb59ZgmkjnmBJOBiazCengdzAMOiDt6ghHnVVVYjCO32ewB/CroMjy+rcvNLRspNmbluOcZNDjOUoiqVTGvyS16UZrnFfdVmOPU3zYjR9/zN6RFXc5ahy1Fn2kJS61TctGtEdIkYOXCR/qJMTDsv3GSSuuoOR8R/Rr/ACdrVlOTA7pAvgrXKhKFbYWu+ZOiy9803UTjgCvNe4t9bPThR8PZVa6S6J53Y6bI9aWFRAN6TrpktY0L44rOp2VM4vBzYZOrcBAAA=)

[image: Application Insights]

Comment: this looks promising, at the moment it returns with `The Line can't be created as you are missing a column of one of the following types: int, long, decimal or real` here is the pastebin of response if you want to take a look https://pastebin.com/95BRJzJ6

Comment: would you recommend book Must Learn KQL: Essential Learning for the Cloud-focused Data Scientist

Comment: **(1)** It works well for both ADX and Application Insights. Try to find out the differences between this version and your version. **(2)** I'm not familiar with this book. I'm working with the documentation.